# How to upload image from React to ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: c#, reactjs, image-uploading, asp.net-core-webapi

I have Web API controller in mt server side

```
[HttpPost("CreateImage")]
    public void CreateImage([FromBody] ImageDTO img)
    {
        Image image = new Image { FileName = img.FileName };
        byte[] imageData = null;
        using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(img.Image.OpenReadStream()))
        {
            imageData = binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)img.Image.Length);
        }
        image.Picture = imageData;

        imageRepo.Create(image);

    }
```

Where ImageDTO is

```
     public class ImageDTO
    {
        public string FileName { get; set; }

        public IFormFile Image { get; set; }
    }
```

and Image.cs like this

```
public class Image
   {
      public int Id { get; set; }

      public string FileName{ get; set; }

      public byte[] Picture { get; set; }

      public List<User> Users { get; set; }
   }
```

And this is what I using for handling and sending image on React client:

```
<form>
        <p>
            <label>Аватар</label>
            <input name="Avatar" id = 'img' type="file" class="form-control" onChange={(e)=>this.handleImageChange(e)}/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Добавить" onClick={this.sendImage}/>
        </p>
</form>
      <div className="imgPreview">
      {$imagePreview}
    </div>
```

function for handling file into state

```
    handleImageChange(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let form = new FormData();
    for (var index = 0; index < e.target.files; index++) {
      var element = e.target.files[index];
      form.append('file', element);
  }
    this.setState({file: form});
  }
```

sending it on server

```
async sendImage(event) {
event.preventDefault();

console.log(this.state.file);
await addImage(this.state.file);
console.log('it works');}
```

addImge function:

```
addImage = async ( image)  => {

    await fetch('https://localhost:44331/api/users/CreateImage',
        {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'cors',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.tokenKey
            },
             body:  JSON.stringify({
                FileName: 'Img',
                Image: image
            })
        }
    )
}
```

But when it`s sending request on server it return Error 400, which means "Bad Request". So I think it is may be wrong type of data sent or something like that. Maybe someone sees a mistake or something that can be fixed. Or someone could show a working example of sending images from React to Web Api server. I need your help guys!

Comment: You can't stringify binary data. You should send FormData in request's body

Comment: I changed my controller so it take ([FromForm]IFormFile body) but now it gets an empty data.

Comment: Also i send FormData from client too.

Comment: For real it gets error 500 but I thing it is because of null data.

Comment: In Developers tools of your browser see what request has been sent to server.

Comment: When I using 
let form = new FormData();
    form.append('file', e.target.files[0]);
    await fetch('https://localhost:44331/api/users/CreateImage',
    {
        method: 'POST',
        body: form
    })

it say that "This request has no data available"

Comment: Do you want to upload one file or multiple files? For the client code, it upload multiple files, for the server side, it only accept one file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For uploading, you need to pay attention to points below:

1. You need to use `formdata` with `FromForm`
2. The fields in formdata should be corresponding to the model fields.

Steps:

1. Change the Controller action.

   ```
   public void CreateImage([FromForm] ImageDTO img)
   {

   }
   ```
2. Client Code:

   ```
   async sendImage(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       console.log(this.state.file);
       await this.addImage(this.state.file);
       console.log('it works');
   };
   addImage = async (image) => {
       await fetch('https://localhost:44385/api/users/CreateImage',
           {
               method: 'POST',
               mode: 'cors',
               headers: {
                   'Accept': 'application/json',
                   'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.tokenKey
               },
               body: this.state.file
           }
       )
   }

   handleImageChange(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       let form = new FormData();
       for (var index = 0; index < e.target.files.length; index++) {
           var element = e.target.files[index];
           form.append('image', element);
       }
       form.append('fileName', "Img");
       this.setState({ file: form });
   };
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly! This decision did not even occur to me, although I thought that I had tried everything.You delivered me from suffering :)

Comment: How i can implement this in .net WebAPI 2.0 ?